# Attempting to Ask a New Question takes me to editing my previous question

Tags: support, asking-questions

I posted a [question earlier today](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22091/using-footnotesize-in-tikz-node-labels), and now when I attempt to post another question I am taken to where I would be if I were to edit my earlier question. I tried logging out and back in and that did not fix it.

If I edit the question, I wanted to make sure that it won't delete earlier question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We store a draft of the post to the server every 45 seconds during composition.

This way if your browser crashes or the network fails, you won't lose more than 1-45 seconds of work.

This is normally cleared when the post is successfully submitted, but it sounds like that didn't work in your case.

Nothing to be concerned about. If you want to clear it, enter a few spaces then wait 45 seconds.

Comment: Can you clear it on the server. To clarify, I am not in "edit" question, but rather "post" question, and don't see anyway of exiting.

Comment: @peter that is correct. Just type a few spaces and wait 45 seconds. There is nothing else necessary here.

Comment: I did that, and still in the same situation. I am just going to post it and hope the hold question does not get deleted.

Comment: OT, but I must say this draft saving is a fantastic thing. How many times I've lost some posts, notes somewhere on the net... I even started copying text to `gedit` or writing directly in it, where I can conveniently hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> whenever I want and just copy final version to the text box on the page. Internet browsers should have local draft saving for a long time already. _EDIT:_ BTW it's sad that `<kbd>` doesn't work in comments.

Comment: @przemoc: [Advogato](http://www.advogato.org) had this feature in 1999, I don't know if anyone else had it before that.  I can't think why it is still rare - kudos to Stack Overflow for implementing it.